# Getting the last event before Purchase was made

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please help me with the query to get the last record before the Purchase was made.
The data set looks like below

```
UserID  EventType   ProductID   EventTime   Price   Campaign
123ABC  Click   P1  5/9/2018 2:33   NULL    C1
123ABC  Click   P1  5/10/2018 2:07  NULL    C1
123ABC  Click   P1  5/16/2018 2:14  NULL    C1
123ABC  Click   P2  5/9/2018 2:33   NULL    C1
123ABC  Click   P2  5/10/2018 2:07  NULL    C1
123ABC  Click   P2  5/16/2018 2:14  NULL    C1
123ABC  Purchase    P2  5/22/2018 4:11  19.44   NULL
123ABC  Click   P3  5/9/2018 2:33   NULL    C1
123ABC  Click   P3  5/10/2018 2:07  NULL    C1
123ABC  Click   P3  5/11/2018 15:57 NULL    C1
123ABC  Click   P3  5/16/2018 2:14  NULL    C1
123ABC  Purchase    P4  5/22/2018 4:11  31.44   NULL
```

*Output*

```
UserID  EventType   ProductID   EventTime       Price   Campaign
123ABC  Click        P2         5/16/2018 2:14  19.44   C1
123ABC  NoEvent      P4         5/22/2018 4:11  31.44   NULL
```

I need to find the last record when click happened just before the purchase
i.e.

```
  123ABC  Click   P2  5/16/2018 2:14  NULL    C1
```

and if there are no Clicks before a purchase for a particular product then just output the Purchase record

```
123ABC  NoEvent      P4         5/22/2018 4:11  31.44   NULL
```

I tried to find the sequence to get the group of records which leaded to Purchase using the below query
 Example

`Select *,
row_number() 
over(partition by UserId,ProductId order by EventTime) as Ordering 
from Purchase`

```
UserID  EventType   ProductID   EventTime   Price   Campaign Ordering
123ABC  Click   P1  5/9/2018 2:33   NULL    C1 1
123ABC  Click   P1  5/10/2018 2:07  NULL    C1 2
123ABC  Click   P1  5/16/2018 2:14  NULL    C1 3 
123ABC  Click   P2  5/9/2018 2:33   NULL    C1 1
123ABC  Click   P2  5/10/2018 2:07  NULL    C1 2
123ABC  Click   P2  5/16/2018 2:14  NULL    C1 3
123ABC  Purchase    P2  5/22/2018 4:11  19.44   NULL 4
123ABC  Click   P3  5/9/2018 2:33   NULL    C1 1
123ABC  Click   P3  5/10/2018 2:07  NULL    C1 2
123ABC  Click   P3  5/11/2018 15:57 NULL    C1 3
123ABC  Click   P3  5/16/2018 2:14  NULL    C1 4
123ABC  Purchase    P4  5/22/2018 4:11  31.44   NULL 5
```

With the above grouping, i need to consider only those groups which have purchase in it and  then filter the data. Currently I'm stuck with this approach.
Can someone please help me out with the query

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/01d09/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table temp (
  EventType varchar(10),
  ProductID varchar(10),
  Ordering int,
  Price int
);

insert into temp
Select EventType, ProductID,
row_number(), Price
over(partition by UserId,ProductId order by EventTime) as Ordering 
from Purchase;


select p.UserID, p.EventType, p.ProductID, p.EventTime, t.Price, p.Campaign from (
select ProductID, CASE WHEN Ordering = 1 THEN 1 ELSE Ordering -1 END as Ordering, Price
from temp t
where t.EventType = 'Purchase') a,
(
Select *,
row_number() 
over(partition by UserId,ProductId order by EventTime) as Ordering 
from Purchase
) p
where a.ProductID = p.ProductID
and a.Ordering = p.Ordering
```

For sure, it can be improved to reduce some syntax...I think it is not a must to create a new temp table. Besides, is this result you want?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the above code does not include the Price which needs to shown along with last event. UserID EventType ProductID EventTime Price Campaign 123ABC Click P2 5/16/2018 2:14 `19.44` C1 123ABC NoEvent P4 5/22/2018 4:11 31.44 NULL

Comment: @praveen, if you understand how I did it... you will know that it just needs to save one more value Price to #temp table.... well, I still updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE_PurchaseEvent AS
(SELECT 
  UserID,
  ProductId, 
  EventTime,
  ISNULL(lag(EventTime,1) over (PARTITION BY UserID, ProductId ORDER BY EventTime), '2000-01-01') AS PreviousPurchaseEventTime
FROM 
  Purchase
WHERE
  EventType = 'Purchase')  
,CTE_NonPurchaseEvent AS
(SELECT 
  Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, ProductId order by EventTime desc) as RowNum, 
  * 
FROM 
   Purchase  
WHERE
   EventType != 'Purchase')

SELECT 
  PurchaseEvent.UserId,
  PurchaseEvent.ProductId,
  PurchaseEvent.EventTime AS PurchaseTime,
  (SELECT MAX(p.EventTime) FROM CTE_NonPurchaseEvent P WHERE P.UserId = PurchaseEvent.UserId AND P.ProductId = PurchaseEvent.ProductId and 
   P.EventTime > PurchaseEvent.PreviousPurchaseEventTime AND P.EventTime < PurchaseEvent.EventTime) AS LastEventTimeBeforePurchase
FROM
  CTE_PurchaseEvent AS PurchaseEvent
```

This will also cater for scenarios where the same user purchases the same product multiple times. I added some sample data to test the query. Check and let me know if they are not valid scenarios.
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3255a/1)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the above code does not include the Price which needs to shown along with last event which is click   UserID  EventType   
                                                                                                                                            
               ProductID   EventTime       Price   Campaign
               123ABC  Click        P2         5/16/2018 2:14  `19.44`   C1
               123ABC  NoEvent      P4         5/22/2018 4:11  31.44   NULL

Comment: @praveen you can easily add `Price` column in the `select` list of `CTE_PurchaseEvent` and then also in the final `select` list.